# Gradle Custom Plugins: Read Compiled Java Class

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build, gradle-plugin

In a custom plugin (or task) I would like to read all compiled classes (preferrably those that have changed from last compilation) with a classloader so that I'll be able to use reflection on them.

Is that possible?

1) It would be great to have a cook right after a Java class was compiled so that I could read it, but I found no way to do this.

2) I'm thinking of something like this ...

```
compileJava.doLast {
    ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
    GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);


    // retrieve all class files
    // for each class file, loader.parseClass(classFile)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a gradle script `getClass().getClassloader()` will get you the classloader of the gradle script. This will NOT contain the compiled classes or compile/runtime jars. I think you want to do something similar to:

```
Collection<URL> urls = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { it.toURI().toURL() }
Classloader parent = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray());
```

If you want to only act on the classes that have changed you are best to do do that in an [incremental task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs.html)